# How do I declare a constant pair inside my header file

Tags: c++, constants, std-pair

```
#include <utility>
class C {
   private:
     const std::pair<int,int> corner1(1,1);
};
```

GCC reports error: expected identifier before numeric constant.

I need to construct the object on the moment of it's declaration since it's const, but I can't seem it get the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to construct the object on the moment of it's declaration since it's const, but I can't seem it get the right syntax.

No, you can only initialize non-integral types - const or not (at least pre-C++11) in the constructor initializer list:

```
class C {
   private:
     const std::pair<int,int> corner1;
     C() : corner1(1,1) {}
};
```

But it seems to me like you don't need to replicate the member in every instance, so I'd just make it static instead:

```
class C {
   private:
     static const std::pair<int,int> corner1;
};

//implementation file:
const std::pair<int,int> C::corner1(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `-std=c++11` and you are using a more recent version of gcc, you can do this:

```
class C {
   private:
     const std::pair<int,int> corner1{1,1}; // Note curly braces
};
```